# How to catch a lot of Jackson Exceptions in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Spring Boot REST application that uses `ControllerAdvice` and `ExceptionHandlers`. I'm using `Jackson` as my serialization/deserialization. I'm using `PostMan` as my client and when I send in different errors such as invalid inputs, bad JSON syntax etc... Jackson throws certain exceptions. Currently, I have an (1) `ExceptionHandler` that explicitly states each type of exception such as `MismatchedInputException`, `InvalidFormatException`, `InvalidDentinitionException`...these are all forms of `JsonProcsessingException`.

Is there a way to just catch `JsonProcessingException` and all its children? I return different messages/status codes depending on the types of exceptions. So if exception related to serialization is thrown I want a certain error message sent back.

Comment: Have you ever caught one exception, which mentioned above? from my understanding spring will wrap it with some spring specific exceptions. If you only want to catch exception and its children, then you just catch the parent exception and you will be able to catch all of them.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Agreed.
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "ee": not a valid Integer value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "ee": not a valid Integer value
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 23] (through reference chain:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create this method in @ControllerAdvice class and verify what exceptions you want to manage in order to return different messages/status codes .

```
@ExceptionHandler({InvalidFormatException.class, MismatchedInputException.class})
public void handlerIllegalArgumentException(JsonProcessingException exception,
                                            ServletWebRequest webRequest) throws IOException {
    if(exception instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        webRequest.getResponse().sendError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), exception.getMessage());
    } else if (exception instanceof MismatchedInputException) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        webRequest.getResponse().sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. This also solves the issue with Kotlin btw, just use: @ExceptionHandler(MissingKotlinParameterException::class)

Comment: @DominikK great! :) anything you can follow my profile on stackoverflow, kind regards...

Comment: Just a comment, Instead of using a exception.getMessage() One can use a exception.getOriginalMessage() which would avoid class and code related reference to send back to end user.

Comment: @NiravShah Yep, basically you can even create your custom one, I mean returning a `public ResponseEntity<CustomBody> handle....(SomeException ex)`   and add any message that you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right.